# NHibernate ISession.Delete

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I know it´s a pretty simple question, but what happens when one calls ISession.Delete with a transient entity?
I suspect that an exception is thrown, but could not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: How about trying it? There are only two possibilities: it will either throw, or do nothing.

Comment: Just being lazy, as this aspect is not so important right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will NOT throw any exception and it will NOT make any db call.

here is the unit test which pass:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestDeletionOnTransientObject()
    {
        NormalSalesFlowActivity normalSalesFlowActivity =
            Factories.SalesFlowActivityFactory.CreateNormalSalesFlowActivities(null, 
            opt => opt.NoOfEntities(1)).First();

        Assert.That(normalSalesFlowActivity.Id, Is.EqualTo(0));

        Session.Delete(normalSalesFlowActivity);
    }
```

First parameter of CreateNormalSalesFlowActivies is the NH Session, if it is supplied when entity is attached to Session and by default is stored to db.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, an exception will NOT be thrown.